# How do I add the symfony utility to my PATH variable?

Tags: php, macos, symfony1

I'm running the latest MAMP (i think so) on my Mac (10.5.8, PPC G4) and I added the following to my .profile - file in my home directory:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin:$PATH
```

But my Terminal is somehow unable to find the command, and all I get is the following errors:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: On windows you have to close and reopen the console if you've changed the PATH-Variable. -> So close and reopen the terminal?

Comment: thx for the advice, but i tried this everytime and i still got those errors after each restart

Comment: I have added an answer to this question on a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787415/how-to-add-symfony-to-path-correctly-on-windows/45589392#45589392

Answer (score 1):

What do you get when you enter `echo $PATH`? Are you sure that .profile is being used? I've had to put my path additions in .bash_profile for them to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

what i usually does is to create a symlink to the utility or an alias.

alias symfony='/where/is/my/symfony/data/bin/symfony'

reload your terminal and the 'symfony' command should work :) else everytime you create a project with generate:project symfony creates a `symfony` file wich can be used as `./symfony`